# How to connect PHP quiz script to html5 game (facebook instant game)

Tags: javascript, php, database, html, facebook-instant-games

I want to creat a facebook instant game like this :

https://www.facebook.com/instantgames/play/602234086894623/

I have a quizzes script here : http://quizzes.mnychi.com/

how can i make html5 game using the php script i have on my website

This is an html5 game like bam : https://github.com/Mohammedcha/FaceBook-BAM-Quiz-Instant-Game

I tried to use ifram tag but it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Please clarify your question to state what, exactly, you need help with. And as @gehbiszumeis said, please add a [mcve].

Comment: I did this is the code : https://github.com/Mohammedcha/FaceBook-BAM-Quiz-Instant-Game

Comment: I want to use the same code on : http://quizzes.mnychi.com/